# Memory issues when loading many .gz files into dictionary

Tags: python, memory

I am using the following code to load a bunch of files into a list of dictionaries. Each file is a json file zipped into a .gz. The total size of the gz files together are about 200 MB and uncompressed, about 2GB.

However when I run the code, python ends up taking more than 11GB of memory before I have to kill it because it slows down my machine too much.

Is this normal? Is there another way to proceed that is more efficient?

````
    with gzip.open(gz_file, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for aline in f:
            data = json.loads(aline)
            listOfEvents.append(data)```
````

Comment: The size of the json files are as raw data although when loaded in memory in python it in theory will take up more memory as they are loaded as python objects not just the data itself. I'd suggest possibly looking into either using pandas as a more memory efficient approach or only using the data as needed instead of loading it all into memory. Please explain what you're trying to do with the data and possibly we can help find a better approach.

Comment: The question should be if you actually need the content of all the JSON files at the same time. If not, you should iterate through the JSON files, process them one by one by loading them into the same dictionary instead of a list of dictionary so that the processed JSON files will no longer stay in the memory.